# AppCode says "Casting to probably incompatible type" when I'm explicitly checking the type

Tags: objective-c, jetbrains-ide, appcode

```
for (NSPropertyDescription *property in [[self entity] properties]) {       
        if ([property isKindOfClass:NSAttributeDescription.class]) {
            NSAttributeDescription *attributeDescription = (NSAttributeDescription *)property;
```

[AppCode](https://www.jetbrains.com/objc/) is giving me the warning `Casting to probably incompatible type` on the last line of the code snippet above. Why?

I'm iterating over a list of `NSPropertyDescription` objects. `NSAttributeDescription` is a subclass of `NSPropertyDescription`. I check if the property `isKindOfClass` before casting it.

Is this just a bug in AppCode or does it know something I don't and warning me about a danger I'm not familiar with?

Comment: I copy/paste your sample in XCode, and didn't have the warning.

Comment: @Larme I didn't say that Xcode was giving me the warning. I said AppCode was giving me the warning.

Comment: I thought you didn’t test in Xcode and wanted to confirm you it’s specific maybe to AppCode.